# How is class property assigned in constructor call without being a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, class, attributes, programming-languages

I don't get behind the magic of these kind of calls, especially the second argument:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
```

The constructor of DllImport is called with two parameters, but looking at the code at .NET source browser, it seems to only exist a constructor with the first parameter (`dllName'):
[Class DllImportAttribute](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/DllImportAttribute.cs,350e83362e7ffab1)

`CharSet` is a property of the DllImportAttribute class, so, how can it be assigned directly during the constructor call with an assignment operation? Even if the class would offer two parameters with `CharSet` being the second, an assignment operation like that is not known to me.
If I would have a local or global variable at outer scope being named `CharSet`, I could assign the value `CharSet.Auto` to that variable and pass it as an argument to the constructor (assigned and passed in one), like this:

```
CharSet CharSet;
DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)
```

But CharSet is a property within DllImportAttribute, so this kind of puzzles me. Any ideas? What is happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Positional parameters correspond to the parameters of the attribute constructor. Named or optional parameters correspond to either properties or fields of the attribute. - [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/#attribute-parameters)

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot, Marc, so this is special to attribute constructors, I see.